# There is already a constructor for a Record named app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, immutable.js

I'm getting the following error, which I guess is coming from immutable js or from `React Native` code. Has anyone seen this error? Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using **redux-persist-transform-immutable** library? if so make sure you are providing the second parameter to your **Record** constructor as described in [the doc](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist-transform-immutable).

```
const MyRecord = Record({
  foo: 'null'
}, 'MyRecord') // <- Be sure to add a name field to your record
```

Hope it helps!